# Fat Free Framework - SQL mapper - load method

Tags: php, sql, fat-free-framework

We are working our way through the long tutorial of the [fat free framework](http://fatfreeframework.com/home). We have made our connection to the database and understand it’s workings. However, we are stuck in the section about [mapping a table](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree#crud-but-with-a-lot-of-style) and loading a single record.

This is the related code:

```
$f3->route('GET /',
    function($f3){

    $db=new DB\SQL(
        'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=liselore',
        'jow',
        ''
    );

        $test1 = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db,'test1');
        $test1->load('id=1');

        $f3->set('result', $test1);

        $template = new Template;
        echo $template->render('views/homepage.html');

    }
);

$f3->run();
```

This is the template file:

```
<repeat group="{{ @result }}" value="{{ @item }}">
    <li>{{ @item.name  }} : {{@item.age}}</li>
</repeat>
```

I don’t get an error, so i can’t see what’s wrong here. Some help would be appreciated.

Thx,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$test1` is a mapper object, not an array.

Therefore, your template should look like:

`<li>{{@result->name}} : {{@result->age}}</li>`

NB: you should not confuse the mapper `load` and `find` methods. The `load` method hydrates the current mapper object with one record. The `find` method returns an array of mapper objects. E.g:

- The effect of `$test1->load('id=1')` is to map the object `$test1` with the database row id 1.
- The effect of `$list=$test1->find("name LIKE 'A%'")` is to return an array of mappers whose name start with a A

Comment: So you don't need to use value="{{ @item }} inside the <repeat> in the template?

Comment: The `<repeat>` directive is used to loop through an array. You don't need it here since `@result` is not an array. Your template would work if `@result` was an array. For example, with such a query: `$f3->set('result',$test1->find('id<10'))`